# Get OpenStack Virtual Machine Metrics

Tags: openstack, cpu-usage, metrics

I have some clusters of virtual machines running on the OpenStack cloud. I want to be able to get each machine's resource usage metrics. I am looking for an effective way to do this, especially through an API.

I have used Glances (a cross-platform monitoring tool), however as far as I know it doesn't fit my requirement because virtual machines will be created on the fly, so there is no way to include the IP address of a new virtual machine to glances config (I am open to ideas on doing that if anyone knows how I can do it).

So I am thinking of creating an API that can run regularly, then send a "GET" request to get metrics at a regular interval. The challenge with this is, I do not know what the content of the API should be. really, I would love an already existing API that I can just deploy into the machines. I am using C# for programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Ceilometer](https://docs.openstack.org/ceilometer/latest/) and [Gnocchi](https://wiki.openstack.org/wiki/Gnocchi) are what you are looking for:

> The Ceilometer project is a data collection service that provides the ability to normalise and transform data across all current OpenStack core components with work underway to support future OpenStack components.

> Ceilometer is a component of the Telemetry project. Its data can be used to provide customer billing, resource tracking, and alarming capabilities across all OpenStack core components.

> Gnocchi is the project name of a TDBaaS (Time Series Database as a Service) project started under the Ceilometer programme umbrella.

Both Ceilometer and Gnocchi actually offer APIs for the retrieval of metrics. Please take a look in the following links:

- https://docs.openstack.org/ceilometer/pike/webapi/v2.html#resources
- https://gnocchi.xyz/stable_3.0/rest.html

I hope this addresses your question properly.

Comment: Thanks for this. I will explore it.

Comment: @'K. Railis', I have now read about Ceilometer, the page mostly talks about configuring it, I couldn't find a working example of how to get it working on VM and capturing data.  It says the API is deprecated and that Gnocchi or some alternatives should be used. I will appreciate some enlightenment on their usage. How do I connect ceilometer to Gnocchi? Also, do I install Gnocchi on a VM and have the daemon spawn on other VMs? That's what I understand from the documentation. Is this right?

Comment: @Kunbi Just to clarify, have you got access to the Controller node of the aforementioned OpenStack cloud? If you do, it depends on your type of installation. Is it, for instance, a DevStack installation, or a regular one with a Controller and multiple Compute nodes? If you don't have access to the Controller node you will not be able to install these tools.

Comment: thank you for your comment. I got it working yesterday. I knew we had ceilometer installed, I wasn't sure of Gnocchi but we found out yesterday that it was indeed installed. We used Juju to configure our OpenStack services.

Do you have experience using Senlin? I am also in need of some help with that. We are not sure which node to install it on or should it be installed on a VM. As I said earlier, we used juju to create our OpenStack services. Please look at my question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63679126/senlin-installation-using-juju-and-senlin-engine-from-ubuntu-repo

Comment: @'K. Railis', if you could see this message. Please I need some help with retrieving results from gnocchi. After creating resource, I am not able to get metric values associated to a specific Virtual Machine. Also, when trying to view these results on Grafana, I am having some difficulty in writing the query for gnocchi. ANy help will be appreciated.